# How to edit files from remote server as root while ssh-ing from VS code?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm connecting to a virtual machine in Azure using Remote-SSH extension in Visual Studio Code. Problem is I can't ssh as root, but need root privileges to edit some files in /etc folder. 'Sudo-ing' in the terminal window has no effect. I'm thinking changing the file permissions would allow me to edit the files as a normal user, but I'd rather avoid that. Any ideas how I could edit the files in VS Code then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using SSH FS extension instead. Created a new configuration with my connection details (host, username and private key). Then in File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > SSH FS Configuration > Sshfs: Configs I added `"sftpSudo": true`, which allowed me to edit the files as root.

p.s. I'll leave the question open for a while longer, just in case somebody can explain how I can achieve this using Remote-SSH extension.

Comment: does that work in explorer tab?

Comment: If you're using the Edit config tab, just add your user under SFTP Sudo Optional.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `bindfs` (`sudo apt install bindfs`).

To enable editing `/etc` as `root` for the current user, working in `~/.bind-mounts/etc`:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.bind-mounts/etc
sudo bindfs --map=root/${USER}:@root/@$(id -gn) /etc ~/.bind-mounts/etc

# When you're done
sudo umount ~/.bind-mounts/etc
# or run bindfs with '-f' to keep it in the foreground
```

`bindfs` has many [options](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html). `--map` may not be the best. It's been working in my testing so far.

Everything seems to work as you'd expect. Lets you "explore" as `root` and any modifications will be made as if you had `root`'s permissions. Just don't forget the security implications!

---

Original answer is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48659#issuecomment-1030989764), behind the fold.